# Is there a way using Rust to add/change/connect to the built-in VPN in Windows?

Tags: windows, rust

Is there a way using Rust to add/change/connect to the built-in VPN in Windows? With example code please

I tried using `windows` dependency but didn't get the desired result. Perhaps my language skills are still too low for this. Is there a direct API, without calling netsh?